# Spring Boot & Hibernate: NVARCHAR column type without @Type annotation

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a table in my database for my `Customer` entity. This table contains some columns that are of type `NVARCHAR` (this is a requirement, I can not change it), but Hibernate is not able to map this column type to the correct property in my `Entity` without using the `@Type` annotation, it's complaining that it expectd a column with type `VARCHAR` instead of `NVARCHAR`:

```java
@Entity
public class Customer {
  // ...

  @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
  @Type(type="org.hibernate.type.StringNVarcharType")
  private String firstName;

  // ...
}
```

Is there any way to configure hibernate to be able to map to the `NVARCHAR` type without using the `@Type` annotation, that is conform to the JPA specification?

Spring Boot version: `2.1.12.RELEASE`
Hibernate version:   `5.3.15.Final`
Hibernate dialect:   `org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, it turns out that the `@Column` JPA annotation allows you to specify the column type (without having to use the `@Type` or `@Nationalized` annotations):

```
@Column(name = "first_name", columnDefinition = "nvarchar", nullable = false)
private String firstName;
```

Answer (score 11):

The recommended way would be to use the @Nationalized annotation:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
  // ...

  @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
  @Nationalized 
  private String firstName;

  // ...
}
```

But you could also set this as default:

> If your application and database use nationalization, you may instead
>   want to enable nationalized character data as the default.
>
> You can do this via the hibernate.use_nationalized_character_data
>   setting or by calling
>   MetadataBuilder#enableGlobalNationalizedCharacterDataSupport during
>   bootstrap.

In application.properties you can set:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_nationalized_character_data =true
```

Read more about that in the Hibernate docs https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-nationalized

Comment: But is the `@Nationalized` annotation part of the JPA spec?

Comment: No that's Hibernate. JPA Spec does not cover nationalization

Comment: Okay, thank you! Your answer works but I am looking for a way that is conform to the JPA spec. I have upvoted your question anyway because it's a decent way to fix it, if you are not looking to be JPA conform.

Comment: There is no JPA conform solution. Btw. JPA is just a layer on top of Hibernate or any of the other OR-Mappers and has only a subset of the functionality of the underlying implementation. I'm using OR-Mapping for 20 years and sooner or later I must use implementation specifica.