# Mapping string field on Hibernate to accept both VARCHAR2 and NVARCHAR2

Tags: java, hibernate

At the moment, I'm working with an Oracle database (let's call it Database A) where every string column is defined as VARCHAR2. I'm using Hibernate 5 as my ORM, and all my string fields are mapped like these:

```
@Column(name = "MY_FIELD", length = 120)
private String myField;
```

This Database A is used on a general software which is used by several customers, all of them having the same database and software installation. Recently, one of our customers requested to change all the VARCHAR2 fields from their database to NVARCHAR2. The rest of the columns, tables, keys... will remain the same.

I was thinking on using the same model for this modified database (Database B), but unfortunately, the mappings I had for the string fields didn't work on Database B. I found that the NVARCHAR2 fields can be mapped in the following way on Hibernate:

```
@Column(name = "MY_FIELD", length = 120)
@Nationalized
private String myField;
```

I tested it and it works. However, to have it working for both databases, I'll have to create a completely different data model for Database B only to adapt the mappings of the String fields, or overriding the affected mappings from Database A. Anyway, there will be two models to maitain, and the only difference between them will be the VARCHAR2/NVARCHAR2 topic.

I don't know if there's a way to map a String field on Hibernate to accept either VARCHAR2 and NVARCHAR2 fields. This way, I can only have one model to work with two databases, and I'll only have one data model to maintain. Or any other design solution to avoid having two different models to maintain every time a database change has to be done.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot & Hibernate: NVARCHAR column type without @Type annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61359440/spring-boot-hibernate-nvarchar-column-type-without-type-annotation)

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you should be able to just set a property to enable nationalization. Then you just have to maintain 2 different configs, which seems easier than 2 mappings

Comment: Use a schema management tool like e.g. Liquibase or Flyway to manage the schemas for the different database types.